# Persist WebView2 PDF toolbar settings & listen to its buttons events

Tags: .net, webview, webview2, winui-3

How can I manipulate and preset the WebView2 PDF toolbar `Fit to width` or `Fit to page` setting?

`Fit to width` seems to be the default but I would like to be able to persit the user preference.

Also how do we know if the user interacts with the PDF toolbar options? For example did they `Print` the PDF or `Save` the PDF. Can we listen to these PDF toolbar button events?

Im using the WebView2 in a WinUI 3 desktop app.

```
private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await TheWebView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();

    // 2 - Show PDF/Web page using Source 
    string PdfPath = @"C:\Users\teddy\pdf\confirmation1.pdf"; 
    Uri targetUri = new Uri(PdfPath);
    TheWebView.Source = targetUri; 
...
```